# Changing css classes of radio buttons with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, radio-button

I'm new to jQuery and I'm struggling a bit with it. I have 3 radio buttons with the third button prechecked. I want to change the CSS class of the checked button like unchecked button with class `btn-outline-success` and if it's checked class `btn-success`. I use Bootstrap styling for that.

Maybe it's possible to "show" the hover effect when radio button is checked?

I tried the following but I'm not happy with this hardcoded way. It also doesn't work and would be a lot of if statements.

But then, if I click on another radio button, the next one is changed and but the previous stays with the "checked" classes.

Is there a solution like in words "if(a radio button is checked){show this with the hover effect from the set css classes}?

```js
$("label").click(function() {
  if ($("#customRadioInline1").is(":checked")) {
    $("#radio1").removeClass("btn-outline-success");
    $("#radio1").addClass("btn-success");
  }
  if ($("#customRadioInline2").is(":checked")) {
    $("#radio2").removeClass("btn-outline-secondary");
    $("#radio2").addClass("btn-secondary");
  }
  if ($("#customRadioInline3").is(":checked")) {
    $("#radio3").removeClass("btn-outline-info");
    $("#radio3").addClass("btn-info");
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="custom-control-inline">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-success" id="radio1" for="customRadioInline1">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="status" value="Seriös" class="custom-control-input" />
        BUTTON1
    </label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control-inline">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="radio2" for="customRadioInline2">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="status" value="Hotline" class="custom-control-input" />
        BUTTON2</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control-inline">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-info" id="radio3" for="customRadioInline3">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline3" name="status" value="Neutral" checked="checked"
            class="custom-control-input" />
        BUTTON3</label>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the functions that you have written:
`$("#radio2")` - this will return an html element and addClass function does not work on direct html element.

Prefer using:

```
$("#radio2").classList.remove('btn-outline-success')
$("#radio2").classList.add('btn-success')
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thx for your Answer. My solution did work too. But I'm looking for a solution that only activates the hover state of the checked radio button.

Comment: Backticks for code formatting, not apostrophes. Or use the tools in the editor.

Comment: You're running native JavaScript methods on jQuery objects here. That won't work.